# This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error during init [Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined]]

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am getting this error 
**This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error during init [Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined]]**
when I try to open a record in vf page with lightning component embedded in the page.
My page is MerchandiseLightningPage.vf

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js"/>
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:MerchandiseLightningApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:MerchandiseLightning",
                {},
                "theLead",
                function(cmp) {
                    console.log("Component created!");
                    console.log(cmp);
                });
        });
    </script>
   <div id="theLead"></div> 
</apex:page>
```

My lightning component is MerchandiseLightning.cmp

```
    <aura:component controller="MerchandiseLightningController" access="global" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="merchandise" type="Merchandise__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size--2-of-6">
            <img src="{!merchandise.Image_URL__c}"  alt="No Product Image" width="80" height="80" border="0" style="margin-top: 20px;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size--4-of-6">
            <br/>
            <div style="padding-top: 10px;color: cornflowerblue;">
                <ui:outputText value="{!merchandise.Name}"/>
            </div>
            <div style="color: grey;">
                <ui:outputText value="{!merchandise.Price__c}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</aura:component>
```

My component controller class is MerchandiseLightningConroller.js

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        try{
            //first load the current value of the lookup field
            helper.init(component);
            helper.loadMerchandise(component);

        }catch(ex){
            console.log(ex);
        }
    }
})
```

My component helper class is MerchandiseLightningHelper.js

```
({
    loadMerchandise : function(component) {

        var action = component.get("c.getMerchandise");

        action.setParams({
            "merchandiseId" : component.get("v.recordId");
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.error && response.error.length){
                return $A.error('Unexpected error: '+response.error[0].message);
            }
            var data = response.getReturnValue();
            if(data != null){
                component.set("v.merchandise", data);
            } else{
                console.error("No errors found");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Finally my Lightning controller class is MerchandiseLightningController.apxc

```
public class MerchandiseLightningController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Merchandise__c getMerchandise(Id merchandiseId){
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Price__c, Image_URL__c FROM Merchandise__c WHERE Id =: merchandiseId];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your component helper, you just have an extra `;` at the end of the line where you're setting your params:

```
action.setParams({
    "merchandiseId" : component.get("v.recordId") -->**;**<--
});
```

It should be

```
action.setParams({
    "merchandiseId" : component.get("v.recordId")
});
```

For this you can use [Salesforce Lightning CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_intro.htm) on your components, it will look at your code and give you details on this kind of errors:

[image]

Comment: I've just added some details about Lightning CLI that you can use if you have this kind of error again in the future.